# How to generate tile with video thumbnails with right timecode

Tags: ffmpeg, video-thumbnails

I'm using FFMPEG library for generating video thumbnails every 5 sec with time codes using following command:

```
 ffmpeg \
-i 20051210-w50s.flv \
-y \
-frames 1 \
-vf " \
    select=not(mod(t\,5)), \
    scale=320:-1, \
    drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf: \
    timecode='00\\:00\\:00\\:00': r=25: fontcolor=white: x=220: y=220: box=1: boxcolor=black@0.5, \
    tile=5x2" \
-vsync 0 \
out.jpg
```

[image]
It gererate right thumbnails tile, but timecodes is wrong. How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drawtext filter is not referencing the timestamp. It uses a simple counter that increments the timecode for each new frame. So, the way to do this is to draw each timecode and then drop frames.

```
ffmpeg \
-i 20051210-w50s.flv \
-y \
-frames 1 \
-vf " \        
    scale=320:-1, \
    drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf: \
    timecode='00\\:00\\:00\\:00': r=25: fontcolor=white: x=220: y=220: box=1: boxcolor=black@0.5, \
    select=not(mod(t\,5)), \
    tile=5x2" \
-vsync 0 \
out.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Drawing text for each frame before selecting the useful ones solves the problem but also introduces performance losses. I made an experiment about it, and the result confirmed my guess.

A better solution would be keeping calling "select" first and using text='%{pts:hms}' instead of timecode.

```sh
ffmpeg \
-i 20051210-w50s.flv \
-y \
-frames 1 \
-vf \
    "select=not(mod(t\,5)), \
    scale=320:-1, \
    drawtext=text='%{pts:hms}': fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf: \
    fontcolor=white: x=220: y=220: box=1: boxcolor=black@0.5, \
    tile=5x2" \
-vsync 0 \
out.jpg
```